# Math number puzzle: 2 + 2 = 3

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

This not-so-simple puzzle asked by my teacher today, given:

2 + 2 = 3

4 + 8 = 27

3 + 4 = 8

So, the answer for:

5 + 32 = ?

I'm new here so pardon my mistakes. Please let me know what you guys thinks about this riddle.

Comment: This sort of puzzle can have an infinite number of answers and as such doesn't make for a good puzzle. See here: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: @edderiofer Well, this isn't quite a number-sequence puzzle. It's more of a pattern puzzle.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Pretty sure the same objection still applies though. There are a potentially infinite number of functions that could be represented by "+", or it might not even be a function but three somewhat-related sequences.

Comment: i bet it has something to do with the powers of 2 (and/or 3)

Comment: I kinda detest these types of questions which distort my sense of adding numbers :/

Comment: I don't know in which world you live or which base or alphabet you use, but 2+2 has always been 4 on Earth

Comment: @ABcDexter Study some abstract algebra; might change your mind ;)

Comment: @edderiofer I've read that you can limit yourself to polynomials and that will be true. You can always make a higher order polynomial that hits every point for a finite number of points.

Comment: @ Νamira Zahra. I am still waiting for your response.Vassilis  Parassidis

Answer (score 3):

Let each equation be represented as $a+b=c$

I observed that in the first equation $a * (b - 1)$ gives us $2 * 1 = 2$,
and in the second it gives us $4 * 7 = 28$,
and finally in the third it gives us $3 * 3 = 9$.

These numbers all differ from their respective answers by 1, and I thought that could be represented by adding a term to the above multiple, $(-1) ^ x$ where $x$ represents the boolean value of $a < b$.

Using this logic, $5 + 32$ would equal $5 * 31 + (-1) ^ 1 = 154$.

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging the statements:

$2+2=3$
$3+4=8$
$4+8=27$

We see a pattern develop:

$(n+1) + 2^n = x$

If the first equation resulted in $1$, then $x = n^3$ is a solution. If the second equation resulted in $9$, then $x = 3^n$ is a solution. Alas, neither of these is the case.

Additionally, the final request pairs $5$ with $32$, which would have ordinarily been paired with $16$ if following the suggested pattern.

Comment: You can describe it as `n + 2^(fib(n)) = x`

Answer (score 2):

One convoluted potential answer:

$2+2=3$
$4+8=27$
$3+4=8$

Step one: Express teach term as its most reduced exponential

$2^1 + 2^1 = 3^1$
$2^2 + 2^3 = 3^3$
$3^1 + 2^2 = 2^3$

Step two:  Multiply instead of exponentiate

$2*1 + 2*1 = 3*1$
$2*2 + 2*3 = 3*3$
$3*1 + 2*2 = 2*3$
or
$2+2=3$
$4+6=9$
$3+4=6$

Step 3:  Note the left side is always 1 greater than the right

SO:

> 5 + 32= 49

because

> $5^1 + 2^5 =(7^2) + 1$
> $5*1 + 2*5 =(7*2) + 1$
> $5+10=(14) + 1$

Comment: $2^7$ could also be a solution since exponent might be bigger than base like in the third equation, right?

Answer (score 1):

My answer to $5+32$ is $135$

**Reasoning:**

The given numbers can be written as follows:

$2*2^1-1^2=3$

$3*2^2-2^2=8$

$4*2^3-3^2=27$

$5*2^5-5^2=135$

Comment: Similar: $5*2^4-5^2=55$